# How does Facebook saves images to my HDD

Tags: php, facebook, python, download

How Facebook downloads images, when you click "Download" near the picture? I see, that they are passing some argument:

```
_n.jpg?dl=1
```

,but how it is managed 'behind the scenes'?

Answer (score 4):

When the `dl` GET variable is set, Facebook's servers add the `Content-Disposition: attachment` header.

See [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1) for details on the Content-Disposition header.

Comment: so when I request http://facebook.com/XXX_n.jpg, it is not picture, but site with extension .jpg? Or it can be done some other way?

Comment: @Maciekp In each case your browser is being provided with the same JPG image - the `Content-Disposition` header simply tells your web browser to download it instead of display it inline.